# change select box value live on change on different select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am stuck at a point on my project where I need to change the values of the select/dropdown box on change of the value of the first select/dropdown box. The values are to be extracted from database.

Database example:

Table: clicks_package

```
cpack_id    cpack_name    cpack_timer
1           Standard          30
2           Mini              20
3           Micro             10
```

Table: clicks_pricing

```
cp_id    cp_clicks    cp_amount    cp_package (cpack_id from table clicks package)
1        1000           30              2
2        500            20              1
3        1500           10              1
4        1500           10              2
```

CODE

```
<tr>
            <th class="left-align">Clicks Package</th>
            <td class="left-align" colspan="2"><select name="quantity" class="select-field" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php while($f = $pacq->fetch()){ extract($f); ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $cpack_id; ?>"><?php echo $cpack_timer; ?> secs ( <?php echo $cpack_name; ?> )</option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select> // mistake in value rectified from value="<?php echo $cp_id; ?> to value="<?php echo $cpack_id; ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="left-align">Clicks Required</th>
            <td class="left-align" colspan="2"><select name="quantity" class="select-field" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php while($f = $cq->fetch()){ extract($f); ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $cp_package; ?>"><?php echo $cp_clicks; ?> clicks for $<?php echo number_format($cp_amount,2,'.',','); ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select> // mistake in value rectified from value="<?php echo $cp_id; ?> to value="<?php echo $cp_package; ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

Now what I want is I want to change the `Clicks Required` select box values  when the `Clicks Package` is changed depending on the package ID in table clicks pricing. For example, if user selects `Standard` from the select box `Clicks Package` the `Clicks Required` select box will display values of `cp_id` 2 and 3 as the `cp_package` has inherited the id 1 from the `clicks_package` table. I want this to be changed LIVE using jQuery. I tried my best to explain the question. Please help.

Comment: Try using $(document).on('change', 'input', function() {  var id = $(this).val();
  // Call the URL from which you are getting the clicks_pricing table data on the basis of the Id selected
});

Comment: Through AJAX It Can Be Done @Shubham.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Create one class `clicks_package` in First Dropdown which will be used in `<script></script>` to fetch dropdown values.

`<select name="quantity" class="select-field clicks_package" required>`

**2)** Create one class `show_clicks_pricing` in second `<td>` to show the result.

`<td class="left-align show_clicks_pricing" colspan="2">`

**Updated Code**

```
<tr>
  <th class="left-align">Clicks Package</th>
  <td class="left-align" colspan="2">
    <select name="quantity" class="select-field clicks_package" required>
      <option value=""></option>
      <?php while ($f = $pacq->fetch()) {
        extract($f); ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cp_id; ?>">
          <?php echo $cpack_timer; ?> secs ( <?php echo $cpack_name; ?> )
        </option>
      <?php } ?>
      </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="left-align">Clicks Required</th>
  <td class="left-align show_clicks_pricing" colspan="2">
    <select name="quantity" class="select-field" required>
      <option value=""></option>
      <?php while ($f = $cq->fetch()) {
        extract($f); ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cp_id; ?>">
          <?php echo $cp_clicks; ?> clicks for $<?php echo number_format($cp_amount, 2, '.', ','); ?>
        </option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.clicks_package').on('change',function(){
  var cpack_id = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'ajaxData.php',
      data:{cpack_id:cpack_id},
      cache:false,
      success:function(data){
        $('.show_clicks_pricing').html(data);
      }
  }); 
});
</script>
```

**3)** Create one page namely **ajaxData.php**. (If you want to change this page name, change in `<script></script>` too. Both are related.)

**ajaxData.php**

```
<?php
$cpack_id = $_POST['cpack_id'];

Now write query here using this `$cpack_id`. And fetch it like the same way you were fetching before.

?>
<select name="quantity" class="select-field" required>
  <option value=""></option>
  <?php while ($f = $cq->fetch()) {
    extract($f); ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cp_id; ?>">
      <?php echo $cp_clicks; ?> clicks for $<?php echo number_format($cp_amount, 2, '.', ','); ?>
    </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: bhaiya there was a mistake.. just rectified it.. its commented there please have a look and remodify your code.. this time I have a problem.. As I have to match both the table so I need to match with values present in both the field. I have rectified that but I want `option value="<?php echo $cp_id; ?>"` instead of cpack_id.. any method to get it there?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by calling ajax request to the server and by sending id of clicks_package to the server and in response you have to return clicks_pricing of that package then by using jquery you can render it.

```
   $.ajax({url: "getdata.php",data:{"id":"1"} success: function(result){
//you have to use loop here for result and set 
var html="";
$.each(data.data, function(k, v) {
html+="<option value=\'"+v.cp_id+"\'>"+v.cp_amount+"</option>";
});
    $("#clicks_pricing_id").html(html);
}});
```